The most suitable noun for old people
One of my clients is launching a video channel for old people. The target audience is those who are old. I suggested to him:
A. Premier Channel the Elderly
B. Premier Channel for the Elderly
C. Premier Channel Seniors
D. Seniors' Premier Channel
Are these grammatical?
He already runs a channel for children named: Premier Channel Kids
He says it should be: The Elderly's Premier Channel

I am aged 72. I hope you eventually come here and provide the chosen name, so that I can make very sure that I never watch that channel.

'The elderly' sounds more appropriate for medicine or social services! I would suggest C as an obvious match for the children's one. (I'm also 72.)

Well I'm a spring chicken in my 60s, so it'll be decades before I get there!

What about the term "Older adults"?

More seriously, if your friend's video channel has any value to that age range, he should be clued up enough already to have positive terms for describing that group.

BBC uses all terms

Many older people in my country (UK) are very irritated if they are patronised by younger people. This can take the form of assuming that older people have certain interests, are ignorant about technology, love to wear slacks and wine-coloured cardigans, cannot bend over to weed their garden, have conservative views, are all unhealthy, etc etc etc. In fact the very idea of a special channel for them is annoying.

but here -[https://publichealth.wustl.edu/age-inclusive-language-are-you-using-it-in-your-writing-and-everyday-speech/#:~:text=Terms%20like%20seniors%2C%20elderly%2C%20the,the%20older%20population%20are%20preferred.] this says:

Terms like seniors, elderly, the aged, aging dependents, old-old, young-old, and similar “othering” terms connote a stereotype, avoid using them.
Terms such as older persons, older people, older adults, older patients, older individuals, persons 65 years and older, or the older population are preferred.
Use older adults, a term less likely to connote discrimination and negative stereotypes, when describing individuals 65 years old and older.

Shortly after I became 60, I was visiting my doctor, and I said 'Am I an old man now?'. He smiled and said 'When I was a medical student, there was geriatric medicine, which seemed to start around them, but now it's called "continuing life"'.
